# How to download PDF using ChromeDriver 2.32 and Chrome in version 57 or higher

Tags: c#, google-chrome, pdf, selenium-chromedriver

Since version 57 Google did remove `chrome://plugins` option. I found that if I want to download PDF file instead of opening it in Chrome Viewer I need to turn on switch in `chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments` 
[image]

Is there any way to set this option in Chrome driver for example using preferences like below?

```c#
private ChromeOptions BuildChromeProfile()
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();

            options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", DownloadsPath);
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            return options;
        }
```

Or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
```

Worked for me.